# how to create to type of user for cms and regular profile for my shopping project in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm new in Laravel and I use 5.8 version I trying to create a shopping website with 2 types of AUTH one for cms and one for user. User can buy items from my website. For that I need to separate the two types of login one is cms Admin login and another is User sign-in. I want to know how can I do it. Can anyone help me.
for customer profile, I use `web.php` file and user route group like this I share:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.index'
]);

Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
]);

Route::get('/shopping-cart', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getCart',
    'as' => 'product.shoppingCart'
]);

Route::get('/checkout', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getCheckout',
    'as' => 'checkout'
]);

Route::post('/checkout', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@postCheckout',
    'as' => 'checkout'
]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function (){

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function (){
        Route::get('/signup', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
            'as' => 'user.signup',
        ]);

        Route::post('/signup', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSignup',
            'as' => 'user.signup',
        ]);

        Route::get('/signin', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getSignin',
            'as' => 'user.signin',
        ]);

        Route::post('/signin', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSignin',
            'as' => 'user.signin',
        ]);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
        Route::get('/profile', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
            'as' => 'user.profile',
        ]);

        Route::get('/logout', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
            'as' => 'user.logout',
        ]);
    });
});
```

I need another AUTH for cms to admin can upload items for sale

Comment: You can create role for CMS Admin , User Admin and manage from that role_id from your table.

Comment: You can make multiple [guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an admin model eg in `app\Models` lets say `Admin.php`. Go to your `config\auth.php` file and under Authentication Guards make something like this

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

In the same file under providers make something like this

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

**STEP TWO**
Open `Authenticate.php` under `app\Http\Middleware` folder and make it look something like this

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  array  $guards
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
 */
protected function authenticate($request, array $guards)
{
    if (empty($guards)) {
        $guards = [null];
    }

    foreach ($guards as $guard)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
        }
    }

    $guard = $guards[0];

    if ($guard == 'admin')
    {
        $request->path = 'url-to-admin-login-page';
    }
    else
    {
        $request->path = '';
    }

    throw new AuthenticationException(
        'Unauthenticated.', $guards, $this->redirectTo($request)
    );
}


/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson())
    {
        return route($request->path.'login');
        //return route('login');
    }
}
```

**STEP THREE** Open `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` in `app\Http\Middleware` folder and modify it to

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard)
    {
        case 'admin' :
        {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
            {
                return redirect('url-to-admin-home');//the url to admin home
            }
            break;
        }
        default :
        {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
            {
                return redirect('/home');
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**STEP FOUR** Finally in all your admin controller classes make sure in their constructor you add a guard `'auth:admin` to secure them. For example

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * AdminController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.home');
}
```

}

Please be advised: It is advised to comment out the original code rather than delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use separate `login` logic for different type of users. You can centralize this logic by modifying your current user table. All you need to do is to assign role's to users. For example, create `role` property on your users table, where you can have two different roles:

1. Admin
2. User

Now, when you have two of those roles, you can modify your login logic, to redirect users to the page they belong. Laravel provides that functionality out of the box. All you need to do is to modify Laravel's built in `redirectIfAuthenticated` middleware. So, you would have something like this:

```
public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = null ) {
        if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) { //check if user is authenthicated
            $user = Auth::user();
            switch ( $user->role ) {
                case 'admin':
                    return redirect( )->route('admin');
                    break;
                case 'user':
                    return redirect()->route('user');
                    break;
                default:
                    return redirect( '/' );
            }
        }
        return $next( $request );
    }
```

So in this example, we're going through authenticated user's roles, to determine which page he should be redirected. This is a basic example of how to handle different roles for users, but it should give you a glimpse  on how this stuff works and help you in resolving your issue. You can read more about Laravel's in built auth system on [official documentantion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication), where you can find more methods that handle the logic functionality. Hope that this can help you, and lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes that can work too but personally for security reasons I never put `admin` logic, code or data together with client data. I d prefer administrator module from `DB` to code behave as totally independent sub-systems under one major system. Your solution works too and is simpler but I'm not that much into **Role Based Authentication** somewhat